# Inserting and deleting a node in linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I'm in the process of learing structures in C and have two questions regarding my code:

1) Why is it showing these errors in `insert()` method?:

```
|44|error: incompatible types when returning type 'void *' but 'ListNode' was expected|
|47|error: incompatible types when returning type 'struct Node *' but 'ListNode' was expected|
```

in the lines:

```
 if(current -> next == NULL){
            printf("The node was not found!");
            return NULL; //<<<<<-----------------SHOWS ERROR HERE Line #44
 }
```

and

```
return newNode; //Line #47
```

2) I have written the code for `delete()` node but feel like the code might be somehow wrong. How can I test/run the program via the `main()` method in C :)??

3) How can I print a variable of any type in `printList()` method?

Sorry for asking these newbie questions!
Thanks!

**NOTE: The program can accept any data type and `head*` is a dummy node!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You need to cast `NULL` to the correct return type. So, `return (ListNode *) NULL`.

You probably want to change the return type of that function to `ListNode *`. If you really want to return the `struct` then returning `NULL` won't work, so you'd need to return an empty `ListNode struct`.

**2)** To test if `delete` works, create a non-trivial linked list, print the contents, call `delete()`, and print the contents again to make sure the node was indeed deleted.

If something went wrong with updating the pointers, you might get a null pointer somewhere and won't be able to iterate through the list properly.

**3)** First of all, `printf` should take two arguments in your case: [more info](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm). The first is the format string, which basically tells it the type, the second is the actual variable.

You would need to know what type you want to print. You need to cast the `void *data` to the proper pointer and then dereference. C has no way of knowing what you want.

```
printf("%d\n", *(int *)mydata);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Pushkin! For 3) how can I check what type the data has? For example, in Java I'd do if `data instanceof String` then cast. What is the command in C? Thanks !

Comment: `instanceof` is relevant in the context of Object Oriented Programming. C however is not an OOP language and has no concept of classes. The type of `data` is `void *` since that's how you pass it into the function. 
Again, C has no idea if it is "really" an int, or char, or whatever. All it knows is that it's a `void *` because that's what you told C it is. You can't do better than guessing its type. C can't help you.

Comment: Either redefine the struct to allow it to accept multiple types (but explicitly), so `int * i_data; char *c_data; ...` (though this isn't very elegant). Or just pick a type and stick with it. `char *` might be a good idea here. You could check if the `char *data` can be "casted" to an integer. If not, then it's a string, if it can be, then perhaps treat it as an int.